# Move domain name of Heroku to another Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Right now I have configured an APP to use a domain name that I own.  However, I have created another app in Heroku and I would like that one to use that domain name.

What would be the correct way to do that change? Do I have to remove it from the old Heroku and create it for the new one, or there is a way to "move" it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask heroku support to transfer for you, but removing and adding is the fastest way.

Comment: Just so the community knows, Heroku has told me that they don't currently support the transfer. I need to delete and add, as you suggested.

Comment: I've got the same problem, could you share how you deleted and added the domain name to your other app please?

Comment: @Boosted_d16 it should be the same way as you do normally with adding custom domain on heroku, check docs.